# Weird result with struct.pack?

Tags: python

While messing around with struct.pack() and socket.htons(), I got some results that does not make sense to me...

```
>>> struct.pack("h", socket.htons(80))
'\x00P'
>>> struct.pack("h", socket.htons(81))
'\x00Q'
>>> struct.pack("h", socket.htons(82))
'\x00R'
```

Where does P, Q and R come from and what does they mean? Can't find anything about them in the docs.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASCII codes for `P`, `Q`, `R` are `80`, `81`, `82`.

```
>>> ord('P')
80
```

In an interactive shell, printable characters are printed as themselves, instead of escaped using the `\xhh` format.

```
>>> hex(80)
'0x50'
>>> '\x50'
'P'
>>> '\xff'
'\xff'
```

Answer (score 0):

struck.pack():return a bytes object.
like this :

```
>>> type(struct.pack("h", socket.htons(80)))

<class 'bytes'>
```

when you show the object in shell,she display in a hex way(symbol with 0x),so if you switch it into decimal ,and compare ASCII map ,may find the origin source.